# System error: -2146697191

Tags: vbscript

I am Running a VBScript(.vbs) file but it is giving me error: "msxml3.dll System error: -2146697191". My Colleague with same set of access and rights can run the codes but I am getting the above error. I went on to search for the error but couldn't find any specific resolution, If I think of something wrong with the file or o\s or system or registry or virus then it should also not work for my colleague.

A Help would be greatly appreciated If I could get the specific resolution to the error code "-2146697191".

Regards,
Anuj

Answer (score 1):

HRESULT -2146697191 (0x800C0019) means "The Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate is invalid." See INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Answer. But If you please provide me some more information as how can I proceed further to correct the Issue.